# Fill Vertical Space of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I'm working on a layout that has a `UIScrollView`, and what I want to do is have a label pinned to the top of the scrollable area, and a button pinned to the bottom, with a minimum amount of space between the two.

The idea is that if the label grows in height the button will be pushed downwards so that the user has to scroll down to get to it. However, if the label is short, the space between it and the button should grow so that the button stays at the bottom of the scrollable area.

Below is a rough mockup of what I mean:

[image]

**NOTE**: The second shot is after scrolling all the way to the bottom of the `UIScrollView`, I want the button to be hidden when scrolled to the top; i.e- simply placing the button below the scroll view is not an option.

Comment: Use a content view whose size determines the scroll view content size. Pin the button to the bottom of the content view. Give the content view a minimal height, but grow it if the label grows too large. Unclear where the difficulty lies.

Comment: You can do this with auto-layout only, if you don't want to add code for changing constraint constants.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with autolayout only, without having to change constraints via code. The steps are as follows:

1) Create your scrollview and pin it to all sides:
[image]

2) Add a view, which will act as content view, to the scrollview and pin it as well:
[image]

3) Your label and button will be added to this contentView, but before we can do this, we must add 2 additional constraints to the contentView. Create constraints for the width and height of the contentView to be equal as the SafeArea. You should set the priority of the equal heights constraint to low (250):
[image]

4) Add your label and button inside the contentView. The label pinned to the top and the button pinned to the bottom;

5) Lastly, add a vertical spacing constraint between the label and the button. Set the desired minimum amount of space between the button and the label as this constraint's constant, for instance 8, and set the relation to be Greater Than or Equal:
[image]

With this, if the label grows in height, the button will be pushed downwards so that the user has to scroll down to get to it.

[image]

Comment: Great solution and thank you for explaining it with the step by step instructions - easy to replicate programatically.  If the keyboard appears (my top item is a textfield and not a label), any idea how to make the vertical spacing constraint dynamic so there isn't so much empty space?

Comment: @Anthony you could save the contentView's bottom constraint as a variable and update its offset to be equal to the height of the keyboard when it appears.
For this, you would have to listen to the keyboard changes and update this constraint every time the keyboard's height changes.
Either that or update the scrollView's `contentInset` based on the keyboard's height.
Thus, the content will always take into consideration the keyboard's height.

Comment: @Kévin is there similar solution for SwiftUI?